# Problem with ALT + TAB switch

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Something has gone wrong with my keyboard settings and I can not use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch the application windows. How can I reset all of these settings?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly "gone wrong" with your keyboard ?  Did you alter the shortcuts in any way ?  Do `dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward` command in terminal.  Does it return any text ?

Comment: The deconf command is not returning anything. I was trying to set a new shortcut, but somehow my ALT + TAB is not working. I tried changing it by going to keyboard shortcuts -> navigation -> switch applications. But it does not help.

Comment: @Serg I have got the app switching now by using CompizConfig. But I am trying to figure out why my keyboard shortcuts are not working.

Comment: See the screenshot, check if any of your Compiz plugins are disabled:http://imgur.com/a/4Cz1o

Comment: use Alt + ~ and then arrow keys to switch.